# Converting .jtl reports to jp@gc graph

Tags: java, jmeter, report, jmeter-plugins

I opened a cmd window at this location:
`C:\...\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext` and ran this command `C:\...\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext>java -jar cmdrunner-2.0.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png test.png --input-jtl C:\...\...\Desktop\jmeter\..\reports\
jpGCgraphs.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTimeGui --width 800 --height 600`

**Error:**

```
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tool class Reporter not found
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: E:\dumps\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tool class Reporter not found
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.getToolInstance(PluginsCMD.java:123)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:53)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:105)
```

I am referring to solution here: http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-execute-JMeterPluginsCMD-Command-Line-Tool-td5681583.html

I have both required jars in the folder: `cmdrunner-2.0.jar` and `JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `jmeter-plugins-standard.jar` in `E:\dumps\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext folder`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved after I installed 'Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool' using plugins manager.

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you refer to: JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar, but the reporter class is found in JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar

The JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar is found in this zip file: 
https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip

Also, it doesn't matter where the jar files are, the jar files must be in class path where you execute the command

hence it requires additional argument

windows

```
-cp "cmdrunner-2.0.jar;JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar"
```

Linux

```
-cp "cmdrunner-2.0.jar:JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar"
```

Also in the post they are saying they have added jmeter home also added to class path but here i dont see that

hence `-cp "C:/pathto/jmeter/home/bin/*.*;cmdrunner-2.0.jar;JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar"`

The error message is saying "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tool class Reporter not found, means the The class in not found in the class path.

Now the overall command looks

```
C:\...\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext>java -jar cmdrunner-2.0.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png test.png --input-jtl C:\...\...\Desktop\jmeter\..\reports\
jpGCgraphs.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTimeGui --width 800 --height 600  -cp "cmdrunner-2.0.jar;JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar"
```

Hope this helps .. Please provide your findings . if this helps dont forget to click answered.